# Show Bernoulli's recursion formula by using Riemann's theorem on removable singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $F_0(z) := \frac{z}{e^z-1}$
for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{2\pi\mathrm{i}\mathbb{Z}\}\bigcup\{0\}$.

Define the sequences of Bernoulli numbers $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ in the neighbourhood of $0$ through $$F_0(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Show $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}B_k = 0$$ for $n\gt1$ and $B_0 = 1$ with the help of the relation: $(e^z - 1)F_0 = z$.

Furthermore, show $B_{2k+1} = 0$ for $k\gt0$.

Ok, I can see that $F_0$ is not holomorph for $z_0\in\{2\pi\mathrm{i}\mathbb{Z}\}\bigcup\{0\}$. To remove the isolated singularity in $z_0$ we use the Riemann's theorem, which says:

Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open subset of the complex plane, $a\in D$ a point of $D$ and $f$ a holomorphic function defined on the set $D\setminus\{a\}$. The following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $a$
2. $f$ is continuously extendable over $a$
3. There exists a neighborhood of $a$ on which $f$ is bounded.
4. $\lim \limits_{z \to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$

So if I use 4. for our example it would be: $\lim \limits_{z \to 0}(z-0)F_0(z)=\lim \limits_{z \to 0}(z-0)\frac{z}{e^z-1}\overset{!}{=}0$.

The limit is $0$, because $(z-0)\xrightarrow{z\rightarrow0}0$ and $\lim \limits_{z \to 0}\frac{z}{e^z-1}$=1. I just showed that the Riemann's theorem is fulfilled, so I know there exist a funktion $\widetilde{f}|D\setminus {z_0}=f$ which is holomorph on whole $D$.

But it doesn't help me much and I don't know the next step. Is $F_0(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}$ our $\widetilde{f}$? It is defined at $z_0$. How can I use $\widetilde{f}$ to solve this excercise?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. It's my first posting, i will start to work on the question and post my problems soon.

Comment: $F_0$ the *series* is the (unique) holomorphic extension of $F_0$ the *quotient*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: $\widetilde{f} = F_0$ (the quotient) in a perforated neighborhood of $0$, so $\widetilde{f} = F_0$ (the series) in a neighborhood of $0$. For the formula:
$$z = F_0(z)(e^z - 1) =
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}\right)
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right) = 
$$
$$
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B_k\frac{z^k}{k!}\frac{z^{n
-k}}{(n - k)!}\right) =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}B_k\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}.
$$
Finally, you can check easily that
$$z\longmapsto F_0(z) + \frac{z}2 = \frac{z(e^z + 1)}{2(e^z - 1)}$$
is even.

Comment: I had time to think but I still struggle. I can see that the inner series at the end of your transformation is almost the term that we are searching. The only difference is that B has index k instead of n. We have to get rid of the outer series, but I don't know how. I thought about dividing the equation by z and then subtract 1. Then the left side would be already 0 and on the right side z^n changes to z^(n-1). Then we could change the startindex n=1 of the outer series to n=0 with z^n again. And the outer series would be equal to e^z if I am right. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Mikemathics, start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series.

Comment: @Mikemathics, and I don't understand what you mean with "get rid of the outer series". As $z = F_0(z)(e^z - 1)$ the coefficients of both sides will be the same.

Comment: @Mikemathics, the correct formula is with $B_k$.

Comment: u are right i did a mistake it's should be $B_k$, will edit it

Comment: @Mikemathics, already corrected.

Comment: with "get rid of the outer series" i just meant that I need to transform your equation to get to the equation which I have to show. I think the link you posted will help me.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{n-1}  B_k\frac{z^k}{k!} \frac{z^(n-1-k)}{(n-1-k)!}$ Tried to follow your equation, I used the formula of Cauchy product of two power series, but I got to a slightly different result as u see. Why u use n and not n-1, as I would suggest from the link posted. The upper index n-1 would be our k in the formula of Cauchy product. That confuses me.

Comment: @Mikemathics, because the product series start in $n = 1$. $z^n$ can be written as $z^0z^n$ but not as $z^nz^0$.